# Is there a dedicated location in my .git folder where I could put private scripts?

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I have some custom filter scripts that I use in my Git repo.

Currently, they are checked in along with my sources which sometimes leads to problems: when I check out a revision older than that where I added the filter scripts to my repo, I get warnings that the filters could not be executed because they cannot be found.

In order to overcome this, I want to put the scripts inside the `.git` folder so that they are present where I need them but don't make problems when checking out older revisions.

I want to keep them in the repo because the script contents are repo specific, so simply putting them to another location on my machine is not what I'm looking for.

Question is: **are there some 'safe' locations inside the `.git` folder where I could store my scripts?**

Safe in the sense that the scripts don't get cleaned up automagically or make problems with further Git versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the `.git` folder itself aren't very dynamic (what changes rather unpredictably are the refs and the logs, so just stay away from them).

If you take a look at the `.git` folder of any of your repos, you'll have a pretty good idea what is usually there.

AFAIK, folders in the top level of the `.git` folder do not usually start with a period, so you could just make a folder `.git/.scripts` to contain your private script files.

If you want, you can also make that inside the `info` folder -- that's really up to you and which you find more orderly.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just include the names of the scripts in a .gitignore file? That way, your scripts are not tracked and you can place them anywhere you want in the repo.

Comment: Good point. While this would work in principle, I don't want to clutter my working tree with files that are basically not absolutely needed. The source tree should be as clean as possible...

Comment: In that case, why not just place the scripts outside of the repo and call them from within the repo when you need them? If you absolutely must have the scripts saved in the `.git` directory, I would vote for `.git/hooks/`. This directory holds scripts that are called based on their names (such as `pre-commit` is called automatically prior to every commit operation). If your scripts don't clash with any of the hook script names, it should be no problem to keep them there.